# Read the Privacy flag using Google Contact People API C#

Tags: c#, google-contacts-api, google-people-api

I have used the Google people API to read all the gmail contacts. Somehow, I need to know the sensitivity of the contacts(whether the contacts are private, or public). But, It seems, we don't have any direct option to do that. Is it True?

Then, I planned to retrieve the group name(label name). So, based on the group name we can identified whether that contact private or not. Which means, the group name have the word private, then that contact must be a private. For example, something like below,

[image]
**Note:** Need to read the red marked labels name. I don't know which property I need read. In-fact, I read almost all the properties, but I can't able to find that value.

I have used the following code read the properties.

```
GoogleCredential credential;
using (Stream stream = new FileStream("credential.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
        .CreateScoped(new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly"})
        .CreateWithUser("myemail@gmail.com");
}

string token = await credential.UnderlyingCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();

PeopleServiceService service = new PeopleServiceService();

ConnectionsResource.ListRequest request = service.People.Connections.List("people/me");
request.PageSize = 100;
request.AccessToken = token;
request.RequestMaskIncludeField = "person.names,person.emailAddresses,person.addresses,person.phoneNumbers,person.organizations,person.nicknames,person.memberships,person.biographies,person.fileAses,person.metadata,person.coverPhotos";

ListConnectionsResponse coResponse = request.Execute();
if (coResponse.Connections != null && coResponse.Connections.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var item in coResponse.Connections)
    {
        // Did my operations.
    }
}
```

It would be much appreciated any one helping on this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

A user can have several types of contacts:

- When you request a list of contacts for a user using [`people.connections.list`](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list) it will return the user's **private** contacts.

Keep in mind G Suite users can also list their directory domain profiles and domain contacts using [`people.listDirectoryPeople`](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/listDirectoryPeople) or search them using [`people.searchDirectoryPeople`](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/searchDirectoryPeople).

**Note:**
You can use the [sourceType](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#sourcetype) to identify which group of contacts it belongs to.

Comment: Yes... My question is how I can identify the private contacts?. OR How I can read that label I have squired?. Any idea?. Any properties to identify that?

Comment: I think you can use the [sourceType](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#sourcetype) to identify which group of contacts it belongs to.